# Invocar Funciones desde Subprocesos

Tags: c#, programacion-asincrona

Buenas Tengo la Siguiente Estructura:

```
static readonly object _object = new object();

Public void loadtacks(){
var task1 {( => 
    F1();
});
var task2 {( => 
    F2();
});
task1.Start();
task2.Start();
}

Public void F1()
{
    //Code
    FX();
}

Public void F2()
{
    //Code
    FX();
}

Public void FX()
{
  lock (_object)  
  {
     MethodInvoker method = delegate { FY(); };
     method.Invoke();        
  }
}
```

Y tengo la siguiente excepcion a resolver:

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
   at System.Collections.ArrayList.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewSelectedCellCollection.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at HitCounterManager.ProfileDataGridView.get_ActiveSplit()
   at HitCounterManager.ProfileDataGridView.AddDuration(Int64 Duration)
   at HitCounterManager.ProfilesControl.UpdateDuration()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Timer.OnTick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Timer.TimerNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Me comentaron que la exepcion es producida ya que se invoca la funcion FY() directamente desde un subproceso, intente hacer el apaño de ponerla en FX() con un methodinvoker pero no se si es correcto. Me dijo: "Invoke the function call on the UI thread" no tengo mucha idea de terminos y subprocesos, si pueden echarme una mano lo agradeceria.

Comment: Esto es una tarea? Esto es un ejercicio? Esto está ocurriendo en una aplicación en producción? Está ocurriendo en WindowsForms? Qué es esto?

Comment: Es en WindowsForms si, todo esto ocurre en una clase aparte del Form.Cs

Comment: Pero por ej con esta solucion la excepcion que tenia de "Operación no válida a través de subprocesos" se soluciono antes la apagaba con CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False, ahora no es necesario.

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir el código del FY? Hice algunas pruebas y me va perfecto

Answer (score 0):

Bueno se me ocurrio la siguiente forma para resolverlo:

```
static readonly object _object = new object();
private bool _SplitGo = false;
System.Windows.Forms.Timer _update_timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer() { Interval = 1000 };

Public void loadtacks(){
_update_timer.Tick += (sender, args) => FY();
_update_timer.Enabled = true;
var task1 {( => 
    F1();
});
var task2 {( => 
    F2();
});
task1.Start();
task2.Start();
}

Public void F1()
{
    //Code
    FX();
}

Public void F2()
{
    //Code
    FX();
}

Public void FX()
{
   lock (_object)
   {
     if (_SplitGo) { Thread.Sleep(2000); }
     _SplitGo = true;
   }
}


public void FY()
        {
            if (_SplitGo)
            {
               //Code
                _SplitGo = false;
            }
        }
```

De este modo FY siempre es ejecutado en el Main thread. Me pregunto si En FX se debera poner algun invoke para setear la variable global seguramente, pero creo que con esto ya lo solucione.